# Cannot Open Image in assets folder for Android App

Tags: android

Just like the title says, i can't seem to get the images in my assets folder to open up.

```
public static final String CONTENT_URI = "file:///android:asset/";
Uri tmp = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + s);
holder.image.setImageURI(tmp);
```

I have tried a bunch of different syntax's, and I can't seem to get the asset to be detected.  Keep getting resolveUri errors about it not finding the files.

`s` is a string such as `hears.png` which is indeed in the assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to get images from asset

```
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(activity.getResources().getAssets().open("whateverResorce.png")));
```

Regards!